# Что использовать для разработки интерфейса на Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, кроссплатформенность

Написал программу, нужно сделать графический интерфейс(красивый), желательно кроссплатформенный и бесплатный(или не дорогой), для коммерческого использования.
Какие советы?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону tk (по умолчанию есть), а также на pyqt4/pyqt5 -- нужно будет устанавливать, например `pip install pyqt5`. Еще есть kivy. Есть и другие библиотеки, нужно гуглить

Comment: Нужно больше конкретики. Зависит от сложности интерфейса. Если предполагается, что будут таблицы, отображение данных с БД или графики, то лучше сразу смотреть в сторону `Qt`. Если несколько стандартных элементов управления и отображение текстового вывода - достаточно и `Tk`.